# Spring Boot @Pattern custom message not working

Tags: spring-boot

I'm just trying to add a custom message to my @Pattern annotation to a project I've been working on from [this repo](https://github.com/jsdavis28/giflib-hibernate/tree/fix-pattern-message).

The Category.java class (shown below) has a custom message on the @Size annotation that works as intended, but I'm unable to get the message for @Pattern to work. When I run the app, the system default message "may not be null" displays despite multiple efforts to get it to use my local message from messages.properties. I've also tried simply typing a message directly into the annotation, but the default message still stays.

Resources I've looked at online that are more recent don't even make mention of an @Pattern annotation and the older resources I've found seem to indicate that my files as they currently exist should work. I know this is sort of a basic issue, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Category.java:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 3, max = 12, message = "{category.name.size}")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}", message = "{category.colorCode.pattern}")
private String colorCode;
```

messages.properties:

```
#Custom message for Category size
category.name.size = The category name must be {min} to {max} characters in length.

#Custom message for Category colorCode
category.colorCode.pattern = You must select a category color.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
            = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

And make sure to put message.properties file in resources folder